# How to build aar in flutter

Tags: android, flutter

I am adding  Flutter in the existing native app [following this link](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Add-Flutter-to-existing-apps) . I tried `flutter build aar`  getting the following error `Could not find a subcommand named "aar" for "flutter build".`

Logs;

```
[   +1 ms] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
[   +1 ms] * Where:
[        ] Script '/Users/apple/flutter/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle' line: 379
[        ] * What went wrong:
[        ] A problem occurred configuring root project 'android_generated'.
[        ] > A problem occurred configuring project ':flutter'.
[        ]    > Could not find method execute() for arguments [] on task ':flutter:buildPluginReleaseDeviceInfo' of type
FlutterPluginTask.
[        ] * Try:
[        ] Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan
to get full insights.
[        ] * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
[        ] BUILD FAILED in 587ms
[ +415 ms] Running Gradle task 'assembleAarRelease'... (completed in 1.1s)
[   +5 ms] "flutter aar" took 5,757ms.
Gradle task assembleAarRelease failed with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`flutter build aar` was introduced in Flutter `1.8.3` and the current stable version is `1.7.8+hotfix.4`. You would have to switch to the beta, dev or master branch by running eg. `flutter channel beta`.

Comment: I am getting error Gradle task assembleAarRelease failed with exit code 1, ,flutter build apk is working

Comment: @RahulDevanavar 
1) did you try run 'flutter build aar -v' and read more detailed error reason?
2) Do you use third-party plugins? if yes, make sure that the plugins have gradle plugin version 3.2.1 or newer, and gradle wrapper version 5.4.1 or newer -- it's important

Comment: I use same [plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/device_info) and have no problem. Try run 'flutter clean' before building aar. You also can disable this plugin in pubspec.yaml and run 'flutter build aar -v' again, make sure that you remove related code to the plugin in your flutter project.

Comment: @RahulDevanavar last version of channel master is broken. Try `flutter version v1.10.3`, `flutter upgrade` and try build aar again. It works for me